# jQuery Auto Complete - Performance Issue

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

We are using the plugin https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html for our AutoComplete feature. We load the source with 3500 items. The performance gets too bad when the user starts typing and the autocomplete loads the filtered result after 6 to 8 seconds.

What are alternate approach that we can take for upto 4000 items for Autocomplete.

Appreciate your response!

Comment: There's a bug. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782638/jquery-autocomplete-performance-going-down-with-each-search

Answer (score 1):

are you using the minLength attribute from autocomplete?

on their homepage, they have something like this:

```
$('#my_textarea').tagEditor({ autocomplete: { 'source': '/url/', minLength: 3 } });
```

this effectively means, that the user has to enter at least 3 charaters before autocomplete will be used. doing so will usually reduce the amount of results from the autocomplete to a more sane count (like 20-30 maybe).

However, this might not necessarily be your problem. first you should figure out, if it's your server that's got a problem with responding fast (you can use your browser developer toolbar to see how long the requests takes to complete).

If the request takes 6-8 seconds, then you will have to optimize your server's code. On the other hand, if the response is quick, but tageditor needs a long time to build the suggestion list, then the problem is, that it might not be optimized for so many suggestions. in that case, the ultimate solution would be to rewrite the autocompletion module yourself or patch the existing one to better scale to your needs.

Comment: The minLength did help for now! Thanks for that. Can you please clarify how this might be a server issue once we load all the 3500 items to a localVariable in jquery? I thought the data is in client side and the autoComplete client side is slow in searching all the 3500 items.

Comment: if the data is already on the client side, then it can't be a sever issue of course. I thought for every keystroke you'd be doing an ajax request to retrieve results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you go back to the server every time the user types in something to get the matching results?

I am using SPRING ehcache which gets all the items from database and stores in the server cache when the server is started. Whenever the user types the cached data is used which gets the results with few milliseconds. Some one else recommended me to use this.Below is the example for it
http://www.mkyong.com/ehcache/ehcache-hello-world-example/

I am using the jQuery autocomplete features with 2500 items without any issue.
here is the link where it being used http://www.all4sportsonline.com