# Jquery Autocomplete take long time

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am making an example with nwjs and into that I am using angular and a Jquery plugin to make a field autocompleted, I am using the plugin named "https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete".

**The code**

```
$("#descriptionId").autocomplete({
    source: $scope.availableDescriptions,
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 0,
    focus: function(event, ui) {            
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#descriptionId').val(ui.item.label);
        //CODE
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#descriptionId').val(ui.item.label);            
    }
});
```

Some description of the code;

The Source is a list of more that 700 records that I loaded from the database.

**The Problem**

if I play into the field, adding and deleting the text after some time the field starts to be very slow each time. I was reading the documentation of the plugin but I cann't see anything wrong. The weird is that if I refresh the controller the field start working fine again.

any help of people with more experience in Javascript and jquery could be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your scenario as there are several factors affecting UI like memory leaks or rendering issues, but I would recommend to put some delay over here like `delay:500` (500ms). It will add a delay of 500ms to server request rather than sending just after typing.

Answer (score 0):

after some investigation I find the same issue reported in stackoverflow, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782638/jquery-autocomplete-performance-going-down-with-each-search)