# How to improve autocomplete performance?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I used https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete and applied it to a textbox for searching and it works, the problem is I'm getting a lot of data and the browser freezes for a few seconds before loading the suggestions. So I limited the result from the query and it improved the performance. But now, the problem is, autocomplete is not getting all possible suggestions even though the string is already very specific.

So what I did is I update the source for the autocomplete as I type, but what happens is, As I type, the textbox is being repeatedly initialized and I get multiple suggestion boxes from a single textbox.

Is there a way to change the source of the already initialized autocomplete?

Comment: Set the `delay` to a suitable value. See the _"Settings"_ section ~ https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html

Comment: Have a look at the similar post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782638/jquery-autocomplete-performance-going-down-with-each-search

Answer (score -1):

You should use lodash Like this:

```
function autocomplete(a) {
   console.log(a);
}

var realFunction = _.debounce(autocomplete, 500);
// Now you can call like this 'realFunction()' on keyup
```

Get Reference more about Debounce from here:  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce

Comment: The plugin OP is using already offers a _debounce_ via its `delay` configuration